# How to insert "/" separator between year month and day in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, paste, stringr

In the following dataframe I need to insert "/" between year month and day:

```
df <- data.frame (date  = c("20220807", "20191017", "20211001"))

      date
1 20220807
2 20191017
3 20211001
```

Expected output:

```
      date
1 2022/08/07
2 2019/10/17
3 2021/10/01
```

Comment: something like `apply(df, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(s) { return(paste(c(substr(s, 1, 4), substr(s, 5, 6), substr(s, 7, 8)), collapse="/"))})` might work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to parse the dates as dates, and then turn them into whatever format you desire:

```
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%Y%m%d")) |>
  
  # if you would prefer the dates remain strings
  mutate(date = format(date, "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Another way of doing this, using stringr:

```
mutate(df, date = str_replace(date, "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\1/\\2/\\3"))
```